# What is an admissible solution

Tags: optimization, sums-of-squares, moment-problem

In optimization world, what is the definition of an admissible solution? This word admissible solution appears in many papers, but I cannot find any definition of it. For example, in the paper "GLOBAL OPTIMIZATION WITH POLYNOMIALS AND THE PROBLEM OF MOMENTS∗"

Answer (score 0):

In optimization framework, usually we work in a "big" set $X$ (a Banach space for example) but sometimes we need a solution that satisfies some conditions (Constraints, Regularity, ... etc). So, we have to restrict ourselves to a **subset** $U_{\mathrm{ad}} \subset X$ called the set of admissible solutions. That is the set that we optimize our functional on it. An admissible solution means that it should belongs to $U_{\mathrm{ad}}$ and a solution which is just in $X$ is not enough.